# Will my eShop downloads be deleted if I delete my Nintendo Network ID?

Tags: nintendo-network-id

I accidentally put in my email wrong when setting up my Nintendo Network ID and now I have forgot my password. Seems to me that the only option is to delete my NNID. Will this delete my eShop games? Will I be able to re-download them?

Comment: Uh... Before you go and do something that may be inadvisable... have you considered contacting Nintendo? They probably have customer service/technical support that can help you out.

Comment: You may have to jump through some hoops to provide the the customer service reps the proof that you are indeed the owner of the account, but I assure you they have procedures to address this sort of thing. People forget their passwords all the time. No matter how silly you think your problem is, they have dealt with far, far worse.

Comment: This might be related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189597/bought-a-used-3ds-can-i-change-the-nintendo-id-and-keep-downloaded-games

Answer (score 2):

> **Your eshop downloads will in fact be deleted.**

There is no get around for this, really if you delete your eshop account all the downloads will come with it, but I agree with @Trent, it's still a viable option to go and ask the customer service what they can do about this particular situation. They may be able to resolve this issue!

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will email Nintendo and see what they say :)